# How to set delegate of text field in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uitextfield

I'd like to customize a `UITextField` by limiting it to four chars. I'm trying to understand how delegates work in `Objective-C` and have gone through the following steps to implement this functionality, still with no luck getting a working solution.

1) Created a LimitedLengthTextField objective-c class. Made the class of type `UITextField` and accept objects of type < UITextFieldDelegate >.

LimitedLengthTextField.h:

```
@interface LimitedLengthTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

2) Implemented the following method in LimitedLengthTextField.m:

```
@implementation LimitedLengthTextField

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 4) ? NO : YES;
}

@end
```

3) Imported "LimitedLengthTextField.h" in my CreateAccount class and tried to set the delegate of the UITextField "ssnTextField" in `viewDidLoad` as follows (my app accepts the last 4 digits of the user's SSN).

```
// Set the custom SSN textfield delegate
LimitedLengthTextField *custTextField = [[LimitedLengthTextField alloc] init];
[self.ssnTextField setDelegate:custTextField];
```

Based on my limited understanding of `Objective-C` and delegates, I've now created a class, implemented the delegate method I want, then created an instance of that class and assigned it to my UITextView object. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to do the same thing. I'm kinda new to objective-C. Can you tell me what type "_ssn" is? Is it an (NSString *) _ssn? Or is it the outlet variable of your custom UITextField element?

Comment: It's the outlet of the SSN textfield. I'll update the code sample to be a little more clear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should not have subclassed UITextField.  Instead you implement the callbacks in your CreateAccount class.   So you should have something like this:

```
@interface CreateAccount :UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
// I use UIViewController but whatever your CreateAccount from.
```

And implement this in your CreateAccount.m file:

This is probably in your viewDidLoad method:

```
Self.cusTextField.delegate = self;
```

and this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 4) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Not a problem.  I only saw Selkie's after I have posted mine.  Good luck.

Comment: can anybody explain it in detail:- Self.cusTextField.delegate = self;

Comment: and what if there are multiple textfields  and i want to delegate all of them ? if u understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @dreamBegin Here, in self.cusTextField.delegate, the "self" would mean the CreateAccount instance, which is of type ViewController, cusTextField should be the property made as IBOutlet for your TextField. And in "= self", you're setting the delegate to self because you're implementing UITextFieldDelegate protocol for CreateAccount and you will handle delegate event by defining shouldChangeCharactersInRange in your CreateAccount.m

Comment: And for multiple TextFields, I guess you just need to define multiple delegates in viewDidLoad same as you did for cusTextField, and in shouldCharactersInRange, you can check if the "textField" you got as argument to this method matches to your defined IBOutlet UITextField instance or not.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should make the CreateAccount (I assume it is a view controller that contains the text field?) conforms `UITextFieldDelegate` instead of custom text field, and implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method also in CreateAccount class. Besides, change the delegate to

```
_ssn.delegate = self;
```

In this case, maybe you don't need a custom text field at all.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have 6 other UITextFields that should not implement textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange. Is there any way I could set it for just one UITextField and not all?

Comment: You can declare the limited text field as a property, then do a check in the method like if(textField == self.limitedTextField).

Answer (score 0):

The textfield that should implement that method should be of type LimitedLengthTextField. Just have the others be of type UITextField

Comment: I tried importing "LimitedLengthTextField.h" in CreateAccount.h and changing the _ssn object from type UIField to LimitedLengthTextField but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you building your UI using a nib? If so, make sure you change the class name there too.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your delegate to a local object which I assume gets deallocated at the end of the current scope.  You are responsible for making sure the delegate lives at least as long as its corresponding object.  A better way is to implement the delegate method in your view controller and set your custom field's delegate to that.  It will only affect that one, not the others.  Another way is to implement the delegate internally with a private class.  Then you only need to set the class and be done.